# Autoit imagesearch from windows inactive/unfocussed/background

Tags: autoit

I can't use the function `imagesearch` to search the image in inactive windows. Anyone can help me, I need it for my software.

Comment: My understanding is that this is not possible

Comment: AutoIt interacts with the desktop _just like a user_ so I'm afraid you are out of luck. You __can__ use AutoIt to force the focus where you need it to be, though.

Answer (score 0):

The popular User Defined Function [`Imagesearch`](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/) is ([according to the author](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/)) based on the AutoHotKey function of the same name.

From the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) it says:

> The region to be searched must be visible; in other words, it is not possible to search a region of a window hidden behind another window. By contrast, images that lie partially beneath the mouse cursor can usually be detected. The exception to this is game cursors, which in most cases will obstruct any images beneath them.